# How do I convert date time to number in datastudio?

Tags: looker-studio

in this post this user use the CAST function to convert a datetime value to a number.
[Data Studio Date Range Filter on hour, minute level](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60769183/data-studio-date-range-filter-on-hour-minute-level/73022974?noredirect=1#comment128972444_73022974)

I use the same procedure but datastudio return me this error:
"Invalid formula - Cannot cast from DATETIME to DOUBLE"

How I convert this date & time format "2022-07-18 15:33" to number 202207181533?

I need to filter a range of value for date and time interval (for example all the data from 1/07/2022 09:00 to 17/07/2022 21:00)

Thank's a lot

Comment: user19572347, [edit] the question with data & details supplemented with images so that it's self contained (See [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176) & [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72859931)). 1) Inputs ([Copy-Pasted Table](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/403501)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, etc) 2) Expected output table 3) Publicly editable Google Data Studio Report 4) Attempt at solving. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

You can format_datetime to a string and then cast that to an INT64 like so:

```
cast(format_datetime('%Y%m%d%H%M', thisdt) as int)
```