# Combining fields in Google Data Studio

Tags: looker-studio

I have a CSV file of the form (unimportant columns hidden)
`player,game1,game2,game3,game4,game5,game6,game7,game8`

Example data:

```
Alice,0,-10,-30,-60,-30,-50,-10,30
Bob,10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80
Charlie,20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0
Derek,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8
Emily,-40,-30,-20,-10,10,20,30,40
Francine,1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64
Gina,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
Hank,-50,50,-50,50,-50,50,-50,50
Irene,-20,-20,-20,50,50,-20,-20,-20
```

I am looking for a way to make a Data Studio view where I can see a chart of all the results of a certain player. How would I make a custom field that combines the data from `game1` to `game8` so I can make a chart of it?

```
| Name     | Scores                          |
|----------|---------------------------------|
| Alice    | [0,-10,-30,-60,-30,-50,-10,30]  |
| Bob      | [10,20,30,40,50,60,70,80]       |
| Charlie  | [20,0,20,0,20,0,20,0]           |
| Derek    | [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]               |
| Emily    | [-40,-30,-20,-10,10,20,30,40]   |
| Francine | [1,4,9,16,25,36,49,64]          |
| Gina     | [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]               |
| Hank     | [-50,50,-50,50,-50,50,-50,50]   |
| Irene    | [-20,-20,-20,50,50,-20,-20,-20] |
```

The goal of the resulting chart would be something like this, where game1 is the first point and so on.

[image]

If this is not possible, how would I best represent the data so what I am looking for can work in Data Studio? I currently have it implemented in a Google Sheet, but the issue is there's no way to make views, so when someone selects a row it changes for everyone viewing it.

Comment: Aranlyde, [edit] the question with data & details supplemented with images so that it's self contained (See [Example1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72565176) & [Example2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72859931)). 1) ~9 rows of Inputs ([Markdown Table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables)) with Sample Data set (Google: Sheets, Analytics, CSV, etc) 2) Publicly editable Google Data Studio Report 3) Attempt at solving. Without a [mre] it would be difficult to test a suggestion as the issue could be [general troubleshooting](https://support.google.com/datastudio/faq/7219787)

Answer (score 0):

If you have two file games as data sources, I guess that you want to combine them by the name, right?

You can do it with the blending data option. Resource > manage blends I think is the option.

Then you can create a blend data source merging it by the name.
You can add also both score fields, with different labels.

This is some documentation about it: https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/9061420?hl=en

Comment: The issue is it is all one big CSV file at the moment, as opposed to different data sources.

Comment: So you want to split the file in different sources?